# How to write unit test for child object?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a test for my Recipe class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Recipe(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    ingredientNumber = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What I have so far is this.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Recipe

class BasicTest(TestCase):
    def test_recipe_fields(self):
        recipe = Recipe()
        recipe.title = "New recipy"
        recipe.content = "Cooking instructions"
        recipe.ingredientNumber = 4
        recipe.save()

        record = Recipe.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(record, recipe)
```

When I run this test, I get this error:
NOT NULL constraint failed: recipes_recipe.user_id

How can I create an User instance for this test?

Comment: `user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'email@example.com', 'password')`? [Django docs - User model manager-methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be, first create a User and then save this user in recipe model.
Ex.

```
class BasicTest(TestCase):
    def test_recipe_fields(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'xyz@email.com', 'password')
        recipe = Recipe()
        recipe.user=user
        recipe.title = "New recipy"
        recipe.content = "Cooking instructions"
        recipe.ingredientNumber = 4
        recipe.save()
        record = Recipe.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(record, recipe)
```